# Migration from ExtJS 4.2 to 6

Tags: extjs4.2, extjs6

I have an ExtJS 4.2 Application with the following structure:

[image]

I'm going to start a new ExtJS 6 application and will move by hand all resources.

I have read that in ExtJS 6 the traditional MVC structure (like I have in 4.2) is not supported so now I have a a View and under my view a have a ViewController that will handle all the logic for that view. Is that correct?

> Does ExtJS 6 support my actual structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional MVC structure is still supported. In fact, it's still the recommended way to deal with a controller that spans multiple views.

However, it's not the only way anymore. The ViewController is intended to work with a *single* view, and to encapsulate logic common to, say, a classic & modern version of a view.

Your structure should work, subject to any actual API deprecations. I converted a 4.2-based app to 6 that used a similar layout.

Comment: Appreciate Robert your feedback. I think I will spend sometime to migrate using ViewController in order to keep it in the best practice for this version of ExtJS. Let you know any news :)